# Can I automatically match MySQL Workbench ER diagram with table data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I created a ER diagram and table in MySQL Workbench as following:
[image]
Now when write the `CREATE TABLE` command, I need to manually match the datatype. If I change the datatype in the diagram, I have to manually change it too in the `CREATE TABLE` command.

My question is, is there an automatically way to generate and match the datatype with the ER diagram when creating the table?

Comment: Next questions if I change a table definition using alter can it automatically propagate to er diagram? If I drop table will it automatically propagate to er diagram? --I suspect you are asking too much.

Comment: Why? Manually matching those datatypes is error-prone and cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0.27,

assuming that you have already reverse engineered a schema and formed the corresponding ERD, and for any reason you wish to change a data type of any of your attributes in a given table from the EER Diagram interface,

Its simple.

Double click on the table

The create table interface should pop from the bottom panel

There one can edit attribute names, type and size.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X81UD.png)